# Google closure library blocked

Tags: google-closure-library

For one of my projects, I need to load the google closure library:

```
<script src="http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
```

But I am getting:

```
[blocked] The page at http://xxx/index.html ran insecure content from http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/base.js.
```

How can I use the google closure library in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your site is running on HTTPS, then you need to access the Google Closure Library via HTTPS as well. Try using a protocol-relative link to keep your site's protocol usage consistent with the way it retrieves the Google Closure code.

```
<script src="//closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/base.js""></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is for base.js , there is also a compiled library in one JS file.

```
<script src="http://resources.programmingclosure.com/closure-lite.js"></script>
```

Source : http://www.programmingclosure.com/closure-lite/

Closure Lite API

Closure Lite includes the following APIs from Closure:

- goog.array
- goog.Disposable
- goog.dispose
- goog.dom
- goog.dom.DomHelper
- goog.events.NodeType
- goog.dom.TagName
- goog.dom.classes
- goog.dom.xml
- goog.events
- goog.events.BrowserEvent
- goog.events.Event
- goog.events.EventHandler
- goog.events.EventType
- goog.events.EventTarget
- goog.events.KeyEvent
- goog.events.KeyCodes
- goog.events.KeyHandler
- goog.events.Listener
- goog.functions
- goog.json
- goog.math.Box
- goog.math.Coordinate
- goog.math.Rect
- goog.math.Size
- goog.net.ErrorCode
- goog.net.EventType
- goog.net.XhrIo
- goog.net.XhrMonitor
- goog.net.XmlHttp
- goog.object
- goog.string
- goog.structs
- goog.structs.Map
- goog.structs.Set
- goog.style
- goog.Timer
- goog.userAgent
- goog.userAgent.product
- goog.window

**EDIT** : from http://www.programmingclosure.com/closure-lite/
A single JavaScript file that contains the core of the Closure Library

Closure Lite aims to solve this problem by providing the core of the Closure Library in a single, minified JavaScript file that can be included in your own web page.

Comment: Cool! How big is that?

Comment: Closure Lite is approximately 33KB gzipped  .

Comment: This looks like a very straightforward way to self-host the closure library. Unfortunately, removing base_c and adding closure-lite does not work for me. What do I have to do in order to get the closure-lite completely replace base_c?